# Arranging marbles in a row

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Samson has $5$ identical blue marbles, $11$ identical white marbles and $4$ identical red
marbles which he wants to arrange randomly in a row.

What is the probability that:

1. every red marble will be sandwiched by white marbles?

   > **Answer:** $\frac{2772}{21162960} = \frac{11}{83980} \approx 0.00013$
2. the maximum number of blue marbles which will be side by side is 3?

   > **Answer:** $\frac{20485920}{21162960} = \frac{938}{969} \approx 0.968$

For the first one I'm getting $\frac{27720}{21162960}$, and for the second one too many attempts have been made.

Comment: For the first, you will need to use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, because you have to be cases which distinguish between $WRWRW$ and $WRWRW$. For the second, a direct case checking of the complement should be sufficient. There is only {4,1}, {1,4} and {5} to deal with,

Comment: How to do it? I have all the theory but getting down to the dirty work has taken me all day and still I have nothing. The first one I did like that but the answer is 10 times bigger and the second one is a huge mess

Answer (score 1):

Solution to 2.
Let's count the complement, which means that the number of side to side blue marbles must be either 4 or 5.

Case 1: There are exactly 5 blue marbles side to side.
Treating all the blue marbles as a block, there are ${11 + 4 + 1 \choose 4, 1 }$ ways.

Case 2: There are exactly 4 blue marbles side to side.
Treat 4 blue marbles as a block. There are ${11 + 4 + 2 \choose 4, 2 }$ ways. However, we have over counted the ways in which the blue block is next to the blue marble. This happens in $2\times {11 + 4 + 1 \choose 4, 1 } $ ways.

Hence, in total, there are ${ 11 + 4 + 2 \choose 4, 2} - { 11 + 4 + 1 \choose 4, 1}$ ways.

---

Solution to 1. It's similar to the above, with slightly tedious cases:

Case 1: The blocks are WRW, WRW, WRW, WRW.
There are ${ 3 + 4 + 5 \choose 3, 4} $ ways.

Case 2: The blocks are WRWRW, WRW, WRW.
There are ${ 4+ 5 + 2 + 1 \choose 4, 5, 2 } $ ways.

Case 3: The blocks are WRWRW, WRWRW.

Case 4: The blocks are WRWRWRW, WRW.

Case 5: The blocks are WRWRWRWRW.
There are ${6+5+4 \choose 6,4}$ ways.

Do the rest of the cases using the above ideas.

Comment: thanks for the input but for the second question your solution for the numerator is too high, mine yields a wrong answer but it's closer to the solution than yours: (15C2*15!*2! + 15*15!)/(4!*11!) You are not taking into account that the same-coloured marbles are identical. Or are you?

Comment: @JqueryNinja What do you think it the numerical answer to the second question?

Comment: I do not think (though I wish I had an opinion), it was given as  $\frac{20485920}{21162960} = \frac{938}{969} \approx 0.968$